# What is the difference between QuadCore and Core2Quad?

Tags: performance, central-processing-unit

In Market there are two types of processors as Core2Quad and QuadCore. What is the architectural/performance difference between two flavours?

I have the same question with older Core2Duo and Dualcore as well. Dualcore is much less in price than code2duo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really need to know the model numbers for the two processors, then you will be able to learn more. There is a [good comparison of Intel processors on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Intel_processors)

Answer (score 1):

A Quad Core is a CPU with 4 cores.

A Core2Quad is an Intel marketing name for their Core 2 series CPUs with 4 cores.

Answer (score 0):

As Moo said, a Core 2 Quad is a Core 2 CPU from Intel with four cores.

"QuadCore" probably refers to Intel's newer i7 CPU ("Nehalem"), which is bigger and better and more fun and everything.

(As I understand it Nehalem supports hyperthreading and Core 2 doesn't.)

Answer (score 0):

I'll say, "n-core" is just generic name for indicating how many cores the processor has (surprise :)).
AMD's Athlon X2 and Intel's Core2Duo are the names for dualcore processors, for example.
AMD's Phenom X4 and Intel's Core2Quad are quadcored.
Opteron's and Xeon's are for professionals and don't carry "user-friendly and good for marketing" names - they can have one, two, four or even more (in the near future) cores.